# wants to insert empty row after each record in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/BOA","root","");
        st=con.createStatement();
        String sql=("select gbal from GeneralLedger where group='Capital'");
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);    
        while(rs.next())
        {
            Vector row=new Vector();
        row.add("Capital"); 
                row.add("");
            row.add("1");
            row.add("Fixed Assets");
                row.add("");
        row.add("7");
            data.add(row);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Successfully I have fetch record from database and stored in my `JTable` but don't know how to add empty row after each record in `JTable`?
Can any one please suggest me?

Comment: its near about 150-200 lines of code. do u have any idea how to add empty row?

Comment: hello pri , please share your code we can see what is your approach when you are populating table , why do you need to space between results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`defaultTableModel.addRow(new Object[] {});`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object[]%29), assuming you *are* using a `DefaultTableModel`. You *should* be using some kind of model. If you have a custom model, then show it to us.

Here's a simple example with `DefaultTableModel`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String[][] data = { { "Data", "Data" } };
                String[] col = { "Col", "Col" };
                final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                JButton addRow = new JButton("Add Empty Row");
                addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        model.addRow(new Object[] {});
                    }
                });
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                panel.add(addRow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If by chance you have no experience working with models, see [How to Use Tables: Creating a TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

---

**EDIT to your new comments and edit**

All you need to do is add an emtpy `Vector` every time you are adding a new row.

Comment: cant we add row without button?

Comment: I don't see why not. This is just an example. Just use an empty row (however you are adding the data) after each row of data. If you want a better answer, then we need to see how you are adding your data. Edit your question with the code in question

Comment: Just add a new empty Vector after `data.add(row)`. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: yes i am asking the same that how to add empty row. i have lots of entries in my table so every time should i add empty vector?

Comment: I dont quite understand the question. Do you **1** already have a populated table, and you want to add more rows to it? Or **2**, when you are filling the table, you want to add an empty row after each row of data?

Comment: actually thank you so much. ur solution works i have added empty vector after each record